# (gitlab to aws s3): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab

This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1.

I have below gitlab-ci.yml file which shows error in pipeline
deploy:
image:
stage: deploy
name: banst/awscli
entrypoint: [""]
script:
- aws configure set region us-east-1
- aws s3 sync . s3://$S3_BUCKET/
only:

- main

I have done

- gitlab runner register and running
- added aws s3 bucket and aws key and secret key id in variable

Comment: Edit: This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs upload to s3 config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

Comment: Edit:
jobs deploy config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
jobs script config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
jobs only config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
jobs config should contain at least one visible job